# configuring karma ng-html2js preprocessor to find my templates in inside a directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, ng-html2js

The problem I am having is that I want to make the `templateUrl: "partials/my-directive.html"`

but currently I have to make it `templateUrl: "app/partials/my-directive.html` in order for it to be loaded by Karma.

this is my folder structure (basically yeoman folder structure)

```
app
    partials
        my-directive.template.html
    directives
        my-directive.js
    app.js

karma.conf.js
```

here is the directive code

```
   angular.module("exampleApp")
    .directive("adminMod", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "app/partials/admin-mod.html",
            scope: {
                props: "="
            }
        }
    });
```

heres the unit test part

```
     beforeEach(module("app/partials/admin-mod.html"));
```

heres the karma.conf.js

```
      files: [
        'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
        'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'app/partials/*.html'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        'app/partials/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {

       //prependPrefix: ???? what do I make this 
    },
```

I'd like to make the url relative to the app folder not my karma.conf.file 
I think I have exhausted every combination of paths can someone explain what and how this is supposed to work with a Yeoman angular generator file structure

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to use

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {

   prependPrefix: ???? what do I make this 
},
```

but what I should really have been using is

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    stripPrefix: 'app/',
},
```

I can then just keep the route relative to the `app/` folder and require the template as a model like this in the unit tests

```
beforeEach(module("partials/admin-mod.html"));
```

which is the same path in my directive

```
templateUrl: "partials/admin-mod.html",
```

Comment: Already did this!  Can't tag you with `@name` for some reason